# how to use a struct in another module

Tags: elixir

I have used import User which is the struct module, but it still have error when I run a test code.

tried using `use User` and `import User`

```
defmodule User do
  @enforce_keys [:username, :password]
  defstruct [:username, :password]
end
```

In another module file

```
import User

newUser = %User{username: username, password: hashpass}
```

```
== Compilation error in file lib/user_store.ex ==
** (CompileError) lib/user_store.ex:84: User.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct User
    (stdlib) lists.erl:1354: :lists.mapfoldl/3
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.if/2
```

Comment: I have put import User at the beginning of the file

Comment: Get rid of `use`/`import`. Neither of those is what you're looking for. Your User module is just User and not Some.Nested.User? And `user.ex` is somewhere under `lib/`?

Comment: the two file are in same directory. in User module, only a struct no others

Comment: Then you don't need to `import` or `use` it. You can directly reference it as `%User{}`

Comment: I use that as the format %User{} as I showed above. But there is an error User.__struct__/1 is undefined, cannot expand struct User. Do you know where is wrong?

Comment: What is the command that you are running to generate the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Since a struct is simply defined via a module, you don't need any special syntax to use/require/import the struct into another module and can just be referenced by its module name, surrounded by `%_{}`

So in your case:

```
#lib/user.ex
defmodule User do
  defstruct [:name]
end

#lib/app.ex
#...
%User{name: "Bobby Tables"}
```

Will work just fine.

If you are receiving an error saying that `User.__struct__/1` is undefined - then this is a seperate issue which means that the current running beam process cannot find that module OR it wasn't compiled with that module.

Two Solutions:

1. You aren't using the correct module name. Make sure you are using the full namespaced module name. e.g. if your struct is under `defmodule My.App.User` then when you use, you either need to say `%My.App.User{}` or `alias My.App.User` then `%User{}`
2. You aren't compiling both files together. To Test this out, run `iex` then inside iex run `c "path/to/struct_file"` then `%User{}`. If that works, then it means in your project you aren't compiling the user struct file with the module where you are using it. If you have created a mix project then make sure you are starting your code with `iex -S mix` (if you are trying to run an interactive terminal) and all your modules live within `/lib` (or what's defined within your mix config file under `elixirc_path`